# Hibernate unique key generator

Tags: java, hibernate, uniqueidentifier

In my model I have an Entity Purchase with the field

```
    protected String licenceKey;
```

I have to generate a unique 20-char Key as value for this field, and it must be an unique value generated with SecureRandom. I tried it with the IdentifierGenerator interface, but it didn't work and I didn't understand how to check if the value already exists and force to generate an another key in this case.

```
@Override
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) 
    throws HibernateException {

    String key;
    Purchase existingPurchase;
    do {
        key = (RandomStringUtils.random(20, 0, 0, true, true, null, 
            new SecureRandom())).toUpperCase();
        existingPurchase = new PurchaseDao().getProductByLicenceKey(key);
    } while (existingPurchase != null);
    return key;
}
```

It is the right way to achieve this? What are my mistakes?

### UPDATE:

Now I managed to use this code and it generates correct licence-Keys. But therefore I had to Annotate the licenceKey as @Id - otherwise it doesn't generate any keys. How can I overcome this problem and force Hibernate generating keys for non-ID fields?

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Answer (score 0):

First, the reason why your code is working with @Id is that, now serial key is your primary key, and the database will throw an error if it sees that two rows have the same primary key; in your case, same serial key.

Also, in your code, the thing is that you are checking for uniqueness yourself. You should leave that to the DB. You might want to read on "Unique" constraint. Basically it means that it is not primary key, but it would still be unique among all other rows.

Now. There are two parts to your question:
1) How to generate a unique key with 20 characters in it?

To generate a unique key which is secure, you can try several framework. OpenSSL is the best one that I know of. There are several tutorials where you can learn how to use openssl with Java.

2) How to make that key unique?

To make a key unique, use the database provided "Unique" constraint. If you are using hibernate, you can use this above your field 'licenceKey':

```
@Column(name="licence_key" unique="true"
protected String licenceKey;
```

If you are using normal Java, then you can go to your database, and add the unique key constraint there. For e.g. in MySQL, the command is:

```
alter table <table_name> add unique(<column_name>);
```

Now when you will be inserting keys in the database, the database will check if that key is already present. If not, it will add that key. If the key is present, then it will throw an error.

So, in your code, you need to do this:

```
try {
    //insert your row here. If the exception will be thrown, then you can catch that in the catch block.
} catch(Exception e) {
    //catch the exception here.
} finally {
    //do something here.
}
```